# What is color "menutext"?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS...

```
a:link {
   color: menutext;
   text-decoration: none
}
```

What is meant by the color "menutext"?

Also, the CSS doesn't work properly when I run a webpage that uses this CSS in the same browser but from the live site. Its correct on my dev machine. For example, some text is white instead of black.

How can the same browser interpret the same CSS differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS defines it as

> **MenuText**
>
> Text in menus.

in section [4.5.1. CSS2 system colors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#css2-system). So it should be the color of the texts in menus in your operating system.

It's however noteworthy that these values are deprecated (emphasis added):

> **Deprecated**. In addition to being able to assign color keyword values to text, backgrounds, etc., CSS2 allowed authors to specify colors in a manner that integrated them into the user's graphic environment.
>   *For systems that do not have a corresponding value, the specified value should be mapped to the nearest system color value, or to a default color. Note that some profiles of CSS may not support System Colors at all.*
>
> The following lists additional values for color-related CSS values and their general meaning. Any color property can take one of the following names. Although these are case-insensitive, it is recommended that the mixed capitalization shown below be used, to make the names more legible.

This should explain why browsers interpret this differently.

Comment: It wasn't the same browser. It was Mac Chrome vs Windows Chrome. :)